# Displaying database table row values using a scroll-able table in html

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

> UPDATE: I just realized that I'm too noob for javascript and jquery, thanks for answering my questions! How do I close this question?

I'm using PHP and MYSQL for the database, I want to display my database's row values to a  but the thing is what if I have like 1000 rows, it'll be really useful If there is a table that doesn't expand as your data floods it with details but instead gives you a scroll option to view the other rows. Please help me, I really have no idea how to do it...

I do know how to connect to my database and to output it but I don't know how to make a table that is scroll-able and does not expand but instead gives you scroll just like a browser...

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('database');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['name'],' ',$row['lastn'],'<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: You need some JavaScript for that. Have a look at JQuery and Datatable.

Comment: i don't understand the difference between javascript and php, i mean the both of them can use and declare functions, can't i just use php instead of javascript?

Comment: PHP is executed on the server. JavaScript is executed on clientside. What you need is a client side (browser side) solution, if you want a scrollable table.

Comment: thank you a lot for explaining that!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello!**

Use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to accomplish this easily.

First, initialize your table with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "..phpFileAjaxReturn.php"
} );
```

} );

In this file "phpFileAjaxReturn.php", you should use PHP to make a SELECT on your database and return the values.

You should use `echo json_encode( $output );` to send the Data Correctly to the Table.

Look at these links:

https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

Comment: You may want to put the actual answer into your post & use the link only for support.

Comment: thanks for that but this javascript and jquery to me is something new and it's confusing me a lot, is there any video that can show me how to use that?

Comment: Well... If you want to be a web developer, javascript is very, very important for almost everything. Have a look at this link that lists the bests websites to learn code online. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sites-to-learn-coding-online/ <-- Most of them have javascript and jQuery lessons. Its a good start.

Comment: upvoted! thanks for the help! but for now i'll just use a simple <table>, i'll study jquery and javascript first then tackle this topic again for maybe after a very long time, thanks really appreciated it!

Comment: @Guilherme, thanks for that source materials! I'll study it right away.

Comment: No problem! If you have any question, feel free to ask! :)